# ¿Cómo puedo insertar una fecha/hora en MySQL a través de C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Tengo un problema. Tengo un método en el cual necesito insertar datos en una tabla de mysql. La inserción funciona bien en los datos excepto en las fechas y las horas.

Necesito que sea la hora y la fecha del momento en el que llamo al método pero al introducirlos en la base de datos me aparece en la fecha 0000-00-00 y en la hora 2019-04-24 00:00:00.

He probado muchas de las opciones del ToString y el TryParse pero tampoco me van.

Este es el código:

```
        public static int FicharEntrada(MySqlConnection conexion, string nif)
    {
        int retorno;
        int activo = 1;
        DateTime horaEntrada= DateTime.Now;
        horaEntrada.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

        DateTime fechaActual = DateTime.Today;
        fechaActual.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD");


        string consulta = String.Format("INSERT INTO fichajes (id,nif,activo,fecha, hora_entrada, hora_salida) VALUES " +
            "(0,'{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}',null)", nif, activo, fechaActual, horaEntrada);

        MessageBox.Show(consulta);

        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(consulta, conexion);

        retorno = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return retorno;
    }
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: que tipo de dato el campo fecha y hora de entrada dentro de tu base de datos?

Comment: Debes usar SIEMPRE consultas parametrizadas. De esa manera, además de evitar la posibilidad de inyecciones sql, no tendrías que convertir la fecha a un string que es probablemente el problema con tu consulta.

Comment: En mi base de datos tengo date para la fecha y time para las horas. Pero he usado el ToString() porque de la otra manera no sé como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Vas bien. Es solo al momento de asignar el formato estas utilizado la función [ToString()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8). Esto es un cambio de tipo de dato. En tu caso de fecha a cadena. Para ello ocupas asignarlo a una nueva variable string. La nueva variable es la que usaras en tu query.

```
DateTime ahora = DateTime.Now;
string horaEntrada = ahora.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
string fechaActual = ahora.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD");

string consulta = String.Format("INSERT INTO fichajes (id,nif,activo,fecha, hora_entrada, hora_salida) VALUES " +
            "(0,'{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}',null)", nif, activo, fechaActual, horaEntrada);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pero realmente me gustaría introducirlo en la base de datos como fechas y horas como tal. El ponerlo en string es más bien un parche pero no sé como hacerlo de la otra manera. Gracias de nuevo y un saludo

Comment: Entonces debes hacer lo que te recomendó @Pikoh. Trabajar con consultas parametrizadas.